# contentEditable not working inside Shadow DOM in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari, webkit, shadow-dom

I'm trying to build a simple custom element that represents a contenteditable DIV. I'd like to use `-webkit-user-modify:read-write-plaintext-only` to only allow plain text. Target browser is Safari 10.1.

When I apply the style `-webkit-user-modify:read-write-plaintext-only` directly to a DIV, it becomes editable. I found this is a convenient alternative to using the `contenteditable` attribute.

Example:

```
<style>
  .editor {
       -webkit-user-modify:read-write-plaintext-only;
       background:red;
}
</style>

<div class="plain-text-cell editor" >Direct element</div>
```

However, when I wrap the code above into an HTML custom element backed by a shadow DOM, the DIV does not become editable:

Example 2:

```
class PlainTextCell extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()

        const shadowRoot =  this.attachShadow({mode:'open'})

        // Note: it works when using plain elements without the shadow DOM:
        //const shadowRoot = document.createElement('div')
        //this.appendChild(shadowRoot)

        shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                .editor {
                    -webkit-user-modify:read-write-plaintext-only;
                    background:red;
                }
            </style>

            <div class="plain-text-cell editor">Custom element</div>
        `

        this._editor = shadowRoot.querySelector('.editor')

        // Test:
        //this._editor.contentEditable = true // Works
        //this._editor.style.webkitUserModify = 'read-write-plaintext-only' // Does not work
    }
}

customElements.define('plain-text-cell', PlainTextCell)
```

To reproduce (Safari 10.1): http://jsbin.com/vugihetiqo/2/edit?html,js,output

Using the `contenteditable` attribute works even with the shadow DOM, but I explicitly want to allow only plain text, hence I need to access the Safari specific `-webkit-user-modify` style. Why does this not work with the shadow DOM? Is this a Safari bug or am I missing something?

Comment: you should try to combine both `contenteditable` element attribute with `read-write-plaintext-only` CSS value. It works with Chrome. Otherwise it's a Safari bug since it works with Chrome (with CSS attribute alone)

Comment: `read-write-plaintext-only` does not work even if used in conjunction with `contenteditable`. I only have to worry about Safari/WebKit. I'm trying to find out if it is a bug, works as expected, or (ideally) I'm missing something to get it to work.

Comment: I think it's a bug since it works with Chrome